# How to move a Mapsforge Layer (Marker) in Android

Tags: android, mapsforge

I am using Mapsforge 0.5 for android. I have added some markers to the map with:

```
map.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(layer);
```

What I am trying to do is change the position of an existing layer. I have a reference to the object stored, but there isn't any way to move the marker. There is only a getter for the position

```
layer.getPosition() : LatLong
```

The latitude and longitude fields of LatLong are final :( I have solved the problem by first removing the layer and then adding it again but that results in some additional coordination logic. Is there some way I can actually move a Layer (Marker)?

Comment: The abstract class Layer defines getPosition() method to return null. https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-map/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/layer/Layer.java Any extended class like TileLayer does not modify it.

Comment: OK, the `Marker` class extends from `Layer` with modified `getPosition()` The value of the private field `Marker.this.latLong` is not even final. It accepts a change to `Marker.this.latLong` via `Marker.setLatLong()` https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-map/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/layer/overlay/Marker.java

Comment: @eee thanks, I just have to cast to Marker in order to be able to move the position... Now I understand the logic behind the API - makes sense, since TileLayer does not really have a position, but all Overlays like Marker, Circle etc. shall have a position. PLease add a simple answer like "cast to Marker or other class" so that I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapsforge treats layers to be anything like render layer, tile layer, map overlays like markers, etc.

The abstract class [Layer](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-map/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/layer/Layer.java) defines the `getPosition()` method to return null, by default.

Some classes extended from it like `TileLayer` does not modify the method's behavior. But, some Layer's extended classes do modify it.

In your case, a map overlay type, the [Marker](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/mapsforge-map/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/map/layer/overlay/Marker.java) class extends from `Layer` with a modified `getPosition()` method. The value of the private field `Marker.this.latLong` is not even final. It accepts a change to `Marker.this.latLong` via `Marker.setLatLong()` method.

Provided that the Layer object is really an instance of `Marker`, you can cast the object as `Marker`.